# preimage of a polynomial union of closed paths

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway p.130 and I managed to solve (a) and (b). But I am stuck at (c). I have no idea how to show that the preimage of p is a union of finite number of closed paths... either about the behavior as c goes to infinity.
Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Conway should specify $p$ is nonconstant.

Comment: @zhw. Do you have a better solution than what was posted? The current answer is rather weak.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the case $c=1$. Others are similar.

If $|w|=1$, then $w=e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta$.

Let $S^1$ denote the standard embedding as the unit circle in $\mathbb C$.

Show $p^{-1}(S^1)$ is a union of paths.

You know the derivative $p'(z)$ has only a finite number of zeros, since $p$ is a polynomial. That means it is locally invertible everywhere but those finite number of points, so away from those points, the inverse image of $S^1$ is homeomorphic to a segment of $S^1$.

I think what you are looking for is the closure of those segments.

As c goes to infinity the segments get further from 0 too. You can figure that part out.

Comment: How does the closure become closed paths? A segment of S1 is not a closed path itself. I think that is the part which seems crucial. Could you explain more?