# Boundary of Level Sets of holomorphic polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

currently I am trying the solve the following exercise presented in Conway (Chapter 6 - Section 1), which states the following:

**Exercise 3**:

1. Let $f$ be entire and non-constant. For any positive real number $c$ show
   that the closure of $\{z: |f(z)| < c\}$ is the set $\{z: |f(z)| \leq c\}$.
2. Let $p$ be a non-constant polynomial and show that each component
   of $\{z:|p(z)| < c\}$ contains a zero of $p$.
3. If $p$ is a non-constant polynomial and $c>0$ show that $\{z: |p(z)| = 
   c\}$ is the union of a finite number of closed paths. Discuss the behavior of
   these paths as $c \to \infty$.

I solved the first two points but I am stuck on the last one, similiar to the post [older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398665/preimage-of-a-polynomial-union-of-closed-paths):

**What one has so far**: Given the first part of the exercise we already know that $\partial \{z : |p(z)| \leq c\} = \{|p(z)| = c\}$, secondly by the second part we know there are only finitly many components $C_1,\dots,C_k$ of $\{z : |p(z)| \leq c\}$, each of them containing a zero. My guess is now that combining both facts yields
$$
\{|p(z)| = c \} = \partial C_1 \dot\cup \dots \dot\cup \partial C_k,
$$
hence it suffices to prove that each $\partial C_j$ is given by a closed curve then we are done. Now I am not sure how we can apply the part of the exercise, my guess is that if $\partial C_j$ is indeed a close curve then the contour integral
$$
\int_{\gamma} \frac{p^{\prime}(z)}{p(z)} dz = \text{number(zeros)},
$$
but this needs that $\partial C_j$ is a closed curve in the first place, so I would need a statement that goes somehow the other way around?

Another way of proving this is to use that locally we have an homeomorphism from $cS^{1}$ to some components, maybe one can use a trick here using covering theory or homotopy theory?

Thanks in advance!